# Get (X, Y, Z) coordinates from Horizontal Coordinates

Tags: mathematics, software

I'm developing a planetarium software using the Hipparcos Catalogue. I have also implemented all the formulas of the book: "[Practical astronomy with your Calculator and Spreadsheet](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/physics/amateur-and-popular-astronomy/practical-astronomy-your-calculator-or-spreadsheet-4th-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781108436076)".

With these formulas, I'm trying to draw the star inside a 3D space using its *Horizontal Coordinates*. To do it, I'm using these calculations to get its *X, Y* and *Z* coordinates:

$$X = \cos(Azimuth)$$
$$Y = \cos(Altitude)$$
$$Z = \sin(Altitude)$$

I'm trying to get the coordinate of point X in this image:
[image]

$a$ is altitude.
$A$ is azimuth.

$Azimuth$ and $Altitude$ are in decimal degrees.

Maybe, I have to use it in radians, or maybe it is the sine instead of cosine. Anyway, this is what I get:

[image]

The stars aren't drawn as a sphere.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I can't tell from your question what you are trying to do. Almost all computer languages expect the arguments of trigonometry functions to be in radians though.

Comment: Your equations don't make sense. And you didn't tell us what convention you're using for X, Y, Z. Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system ?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Using the notation in your diagram.

$$x = \cos (a) \cos (A)$$
$$ y = \cos (a) \sin (A)$$
$$z = \sin (a)$$

In most computer codes, all the angles should be in radians, where $\theta_{\rm rad} = \theta_{\rm deg} \times \pi/180$.

Note that if comparing with other sources, you do have to pay attention to how the angles are defined. For instance, the altitude is $90^{\circ} -$ the usual polar angle in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: I think it is $x = \sin (a) \cos (A)$ and $y = \sin (a) \sin (A)$. At least, this is how this formula appears in my Calculus book (and also in Wikipedia).

Comment: @VansFannel I don't think so.

Comment: Well, you can believe whatever you want. Just look it up on Wikipedia and check what I say.

Comment: @VansFannel put the link here and I might. You might be confused with polar coordinates, where the expression would be $x = \sin\theta \cos\phi$ etc

Comment: https://openstax.org/books/c%C3%A1lculo-volumen-3/pages/2-7-coordenadas-cilindricas-y-esfericas and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates @ProfRob

Comment: @VansFannel both of those sources are in perfect agreement with my answer. You DO have to pay attention to how the angles are defined.

Comment: Both sets of equations can be correct depending on how the angles are expressed.  But the way profrob presented them is the way they're most often used in astronomy today.

Comment: @GregMiller only one of them is correct for the angles **as defined by the OP in their own question!**

Comment: I can’t promise it will solve your issue, but I had a similar problem once, and to my surprise, I solved it by using, for example, y and z instead of x and y, or x and z, or any other such combination.